# Server power requirements

Tags: power-supply, voltage, energy

The computers that I’ve been exposed to only require a typical American 120 volt outlet to the PSU. From what I understand, depending on the homes electrical layout you’re limited to about 15 amps, which ends up being 1800 watts.

What are the requirements and methods of delivering electricity to these high-end servers (8 GPU servers, etc.)? Are there two 120 volts that are combined somehow? Do you use an outlet similar to what you plug a dryer into?

I’ve had trouble finding a good source describing this topic. I can’t seem to find the this information on manufacture websites either.

Comment: This depends on the design of the setup. In a rack mount environment, the servers per rack may fit into a 120 Volt 15 or 20 Amp setup with each rack on a separate circuit.   I have see this before. Dryer circuits are typically 240 Volt 20 or 30 Amp circuits and then servers would need 240 Power Supplies. "It depends"

Comment: "What are the requirements and methods of delivering electricity to these high-end servers (8 GPU servers, etc.)?" - This entirely depends on the hardware contained within the hardware.  Additionally, your circuit breaker limits will entirely depend on your electrician's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vendor's product spec sheet should give you the number of PSUs and their rating. For example, [this](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=a00039976enw) spec sheet specifies either two or four PSUs and the picture of the rear of the system shows the power connectors. While the spec sheet does not say it explicitly, these look like C20 connectors. Other vendors will publish similar sheets for their servers. FYI, the more standard C13 power cord is more common on lower-end servers.